# Injected DLL not writing file

Tags: winapi, dll, hook

I am writing C code, using WinAPI, that installs a global hook (WH_GETMESSAGE) which injects a DLL into all compatible processes in the system. The injected DLL monitors a certain messages passed to the message queue and creates a text file. The callback function in the DLL should create a text file using a randomly generated name in a specific directory. The methods are working when tested on *main* but fail when in the DLL (i.e no text file is created). NB: The following are working fine.

- The DLL is successfully injected into all (32bit) processes, checked using
  ProcessExplorer.
- The Callback function is being called, checked using
  `MessageBeep(-1)`

**Is there something I am missing in the code? and are there any ways to debug my DLL code injected in a processes e.g in Firefox.**

Here's my code in the DLL:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
    if (code < 0) {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
        if ((code == HC_ACTION) && (wParam == PM_REMOVE)){
//for any message create and write to text file 
            writeToLogFile(); 
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Here's the code that creates the text file:

```
BOOL writeToLogFile() {
    char fileName[10];
    char fName[] = "C:\\Users\\MyDir\\";
    char buffer[75]; //place concatenated string here
    generateRandomStr(fileName); //methos to generate file name
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s%s.txt", fName, fileName);
    HANDLE fHandle =
        CreateFile(buffer,
            FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);

//file handle code check ommited for brevity
        DWORD bytesWritten;
        WriteFile(fHandle, buffer, strlen(buffer), &bytesWritten, NULL);
        CloseHandle(fHandle);
        return TRUE;
    }

   /*Generate file name string (a-z characters)*/
    VOID generateRandomStr(char holder[]) {
        size_t i = 0;
        srand(time(NULL)); //system clock seconds for seed 
        while (i < 9) {
            int x = (97 + rand() % 97);
            if (x > 96 && x < 122) {
                holder[i] = ((char)x);
                //puts((char)x);
                i++;
            }
        }
        holder[i++] = '\0'; //terminate the string
```

Comment: You should do some debugging. Find out where the code fails.

Comment: That's my main problem, how to debug the injected DLL from its host process.

Comment: Many less experienced programmers don't appreciate that there is more to debugging than an interactive debugger. There are many forms of debugging. You need trace debugging. Add calls to `OutputDebugString` and watch the output appear in, for example, SysInternals DbgView. Take this opportunity to learn some more advanced debugging techniques that will help you become a much better programmer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try DbgView and see if it helps.

Comment: @Kelli: you say that the "*file handle code check ommited for brevity*", but is that code actually catching any errors?  What about any errors on `WriteFile()`?  Also, does the injected host process even have permissions to write to the target folder to begin with? Does the folder even exist before you attempt to create the file?  `CreateFile()` does not create non-existant folders, you need to call `CreateDirectory()` for that.

Comment: You can debug your code in another process. One easy way is to add a Sleep() to the hook that gives you enough time to attach a debugger (e.g. 20 seconds). Set a breakpoint on the line after the Sleep() call. Then run your program (normally), and while the target process is in the Sleep() call you can attach the debugger to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116253/Hot-Patching-Made-Easy. It talks about DLL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the comments and tips. Finally managed to make it work, the issue was with the function `CreateFile` which was failing (some illegal characters in the file name generated). After using the `OutputDebugString`, I was able to view the output and debugged the `generateRandomStr` function responsible for generating the filename and it worked.